# Django/Python mailing list implementation

Tags: python, django

My site requires sending periodic update emails to all our registered clients.

To keep our lists clear, I want to track all failed deliveries and purge the mailing lists accordingly. I am assuming I am not the first nor the last to do this.

Can anyone recommend an existing app/library that I can use to accomplish this goal ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/)

Comment: While I was loath to use them at first (free is better than paid). Looks like they are going to be my choice after I took a look at their APIs.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need a mailing list server like [mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html), there is [django-mailman](https://launchpad.net/django-mailman) (a django's admin interface for mailman), and follow this steps:

- Install mailman
- Install django-mailman
- Complete your user's registration algorithm for your users and register them in mailman.
- When you need send a mail, send it to you mailman list.
- Have a lot of fun!